# MS Access Combobox show tabs

Tags: ms-access, combobox, tabs, ms-access-2010

I am putting together a web form and I want to show or hide tabs based on a combobox. I'm not exactly sure how to do this in the best way. The combo box is just 1-10 and if 3 is selected, I want it to display 3 tabs, etc.

I can take a really roundabout way and hide everything with macros, but is there an easier way to reference the tabs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each tab has a name and you can hide/show tabs using `Visible` property

```
tabMyTab3.Visible = False
```

Comment: Right. But let's say I want to, by default, hide all 10 tabs. Then, with my combobox, the only way I've been able to come up with showing/hiding them is to directly reference every tab. For example:

Comment: Show the first tab but hide all the others. Then, if combobox=2, show the first 2 tabs but hide everything else. Then, if combobox=3, show the first 3 tabs but hide the rest. But that requires for every option to manually call out each of the tabs for every number.

Is there an easier way to show/hide multiple tabs?

Comment: Mind you, this is a web form, so I either have to be able to set it up as a macro or copy/paste appropriate web formats only.